# Directing output from command to folder

Tags: bash, shell-script, pdf

I am using pdfdetach utility which would extract embedded objects in PDF files and dump them to the current folder. Output can be anything such as .doc files or others. All I want to do is that whatever the output of the pdfdetach, I want it to be stored in sub-directory instead of current directory by default.

Here is the simple line I am trying but is not working:

```
pdfdetach -saveall JSPopupCalendar.pdf > /subfolder/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "-o" argument.  e.g. `pdfdetach -saveall JSPopupCalendar.pdf -o /subfolder`

See man page http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/pdfdetach.1.html

> -saveall
>
> Save all of the embedded files.  This uses  the  file  names  associated  with  the
>                 embedded files (as printed by the "-list" switch).  By default, the files are saved
>                 in the current directory; this can be changed with the "-o" switch.
>
> -o path
>
> Set the file name used when saving an embedded file with the "-save" 
>   switch, or the
>                directory used by "-saveall".

Example, showing how we detach the KSBASE.WQ2 file from inside fileAttachment.pdf.

```
$ pdfdetach -saveall fileAttachment.pdf -o bar
$ find . -ls
 384329    0 drwxrwxr-x   3 steve    steve          43 Sep  7 17:42 .
9137752    0 drwxrwxr-x   2 steve    steve          24 Sep  7 17:42 ./bar
8544834   24 -rw-rw-r--   1 steve    steve       20668 Sep  7 17:42 ./bar/KSBASE.WQ2
 384331   80 -rw-rw-r--   1 steve    steve       78950 Nov  2  2017 ./fileAttachment.pdf
$
```

Comment: Hi Steve. i tried this prior to posting and for reassurance, I tried it again now. I keep getting this error in terminal: I/O Error: Error saving embedded file as ''

Comment: Please update your question to include (1) initial output of `find . -ls`, (2) exact pdfdetach command and subsequent output seen when fails, and (3) output of `pdfdetach -list JSPopupCalendar.pdf`

Comment: Brilliant! To do as requested, I deleted the output that was generated previously by the command. Then when I tried the command again, it worked. So apparently you get that error message when a file with the same name in the directory exist. Thanks Steve